# Which Azure Storage method is best for a temporary file transfer?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to automate the transfer of files from a website not hosted in Azure to my client’s premises.

I am considering having an API on the website send the files to Azure Blob Storage , and then having another API running at the client site, download them.

Both would make use of the Azure storage API, which I like because it is easy to implement.

The files do not need to stay in Azure and can be deleted from storage once they are downloaded.

However I am wondering if there is a faster way.

Should I be using Hot Blob Storage or File Storage perhaps?

I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers but am still unclear as to the fastest method for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you can use File share, which can be [mapped to local as a mapped drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows#map-the-azure-file-share-to-a-windows-drive) and can be easily and faster operation like read / delete.

If you choose code only, from the [comparison of blob and file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks#comparison-files-and-blobs), they can be up to Up to 60 MiB/s, I cannot see which is faster. There is a [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#microsoft-azure-storage-data-movement-library-0101) , which is designed for high-performance uploading, downloading and copying Azure Storage Blob and File, you can use it for your purpose.

Comment: looks like the storage data movement library will help.  I am still not clear on hot vs cold.

Comment: For hot and cool tier of blob, the main difference is user charge, nothing to do with speed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend blob storage for this application. Logic apps can also be used to automate this pipeline based on timer triggers or some other trigger.

Comment: hot or cold? given the use case.